# How to find the binding triggering a System.Windows.Data Error 4 in the debug logs

Tags: wpf, xaml, debugging, binding

I've one big WPF application, at some point we create a lot of objects(and a lot of GUI are bound to the newly selected object with a lot of subcontrols.

This generate a bunch of binding error, of 2 types:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'ListBoxItem' (Name=''); target property is 'HorizontalContentAlignment' (type 'HorizontalAlignment')
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=VerticalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'ListBoxItem' (Name=''); target property is 'VerticalContentAlignment' (type 'VerticalAlignment')
```

(each error is displayed ~10-20 times).

I've looked for solution prior to asking but:

1. If I use snoop to see the part of GUI that triggers error, I don't get errors anymore
2. Looking for parts of errors. I've double-checked, but we bind nowhere VerticalContentAlignement or its horizontal counterparts, it's always bound to a given value
3. I cannot find the binding that would be missing(and maybe it's one of those temporary state)

I'm kind of lost, I don't see how I can debug this? We were having a lot of binding errors in the past and now we want to have none, in order to easily see if there is an issue with something we are developing.

Comment: Check your Styles and ControlTemplates. You could have a ListBoxItem without a parent ListBox somewhere, and it could also be a class you wrote that inherits either of them, that also has Style and/or with ControlTemplate(target type of inheriting class) that is missing some vital part.

Comment: @o_w Yeah for sure, but which one? We have more than 500 views and even more usage of listbox

Comment: I was trying to say to check your resources(styles and such usually go there), so start with App.xaml and App.xaml.cs.  Check if you inherit ListBoxItem or ListBox, and search solution xaml files for mention of said class.

Comment: Another thing that can help you is tracing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-display-wpf-trace-information?view=vs-2019